# railstutorial.org - undefined method `Factory'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm attempting to follow railstutorial.org, and am currently on Chapter 7, where you start using factories: http://railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two#sec:tests_with_factories

I'm using Rails 3.0.1 and ruby-1.9.2-p0

I can't for the life of me get my rspec tests to pass though, the error i get is

```
Failures:
    1) UsersController GET 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     undefined method `Factory' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x00000101cc5608>
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

my factories.rb looks like this:

```
# By using the symbol ':user', we get Factory Girl to simulate the User model.
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Michael Hartl"
  user.email                 "mhartl@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

and this is my `users_controller_spec.rb` file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'show'" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = Factory(:user)
    end
    it "should be successful" do
      get :show, :id => @user
      response.should be_success
    end
```

here is my Gemfile, if it helps:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'gravatar_image_tag'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'annotate-models'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should try the new syntax (see [github readme](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) of factory girl)

```
FactoryGirl.define :user do |user|
  user.name                  "Michael Hartl"
  user.email                 "mhartl@example.com"
  user.password              "foobar"
  user.password_confirmation "foobar"
end
```

Answer (score 21):

As per the latest version of Factory Girl (currently v4.0.0)
rewrite factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
  factory :user do
    name                  "Michael Hartl"
    email                 "mhartl@example.com"
    password              "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

then call it from your users controller specs as:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Answer (score 12):

I got this exact same error message. I just restarted my Spork server and Autotest and everything went green for me.

Comment: +1 This fixed the problem for me to with the FactoryGirl version from the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

In your spec use

```
  @user = FactoryGirl(:user)
```

instead of

```
  @user = Factory(:user)
```

Comment: Instead of FactoryGirl(:user), useFactoryGirl.create(:user) as suggested by @Postscripter

Comment: create is implicitly called

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, but it was because I had placed the factory girl gem under the development section instead of the test section of the Gemfile. Once under the test section, it worked. One difference I note between my entry and yours is that mine specifies 1.0:

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to add `require 'factory_girl'` to `test_helper.rb`

Answer (score 0):

My solution: I've accidentally included it in the `:development` block, and simply had to move it to the `:test` block

(I've listed it here, because it might help someone who doesn't follow the tutorial correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I have done so, 
add `require 'factory_girl'` to `test_helper.rb` and

```
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this page now: note where you once used "FactoryGirl" you must now use "FactoryBot" in your tests. From the thoughtbot announcement page:

> "We’re renaming factory_girl to factory_bot (and factory_girl_rails to
>   factory_bot_rails). All the same functionality of factory_girl, now
>   under a different name."

More details here:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/factory_bot

Answer (score -1):

I was determined to use the newest version of Factory Girl, so I tried to adapt the code. Didn't work for me, so I used

```
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
```

in the Gemfile to lock the version at 1.0

```
bundle update
```

restart spork and autotest and it worked.