# Rspec failure when it should be passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, factory-bot

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec/` I have one of my tests fail that should be passing. Here's the error:

```
Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `Factory' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x1037c0a70>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:21
```

Here's the test code:

```
  describe "GET 'show'" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = Factory(:user)
  end

  it "should be successful" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should find the right user" do
    get :show, :id => @user
    assigns(:user).should == @user
  end
end
```

I installed the Factory Girl gem, so I'm unsure what the issue is.

Comment: Did you include factory-girl in your `Gemfile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you installed `factory_girl`, but is it in both your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files? (You may need to `bundle install` to get it into `Gemfile.lock`). Since you're using `bundle exec`, bundler will check your `Gemfile.lock` for the gems it should load.

[Edit]

On second thought, this looks like a [duplicate of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991052/railstutorial-org-undefined-method-factory).

Comment: yeah, I initially ran `bundle install` and I see factory girl in my `Gemfile.lock` file. Don't think that's it.

Comment: I have `gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'` only in the `group :test do` block. I don't think this is it either.

Comment: One last suggestion: check out the [link in my edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991052/railstutorial-org-undefined-method-factory).

Comment: Oh never mind, this was stupid. I just had to restart spork  :/

Comment: I'll give it to you anyway because you're basically right about it being a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not the case, but have you tried restarting the web server ?

Answer (score 0):

The answers in this did not help me. What I found to solve my problem was to add a line to spec_helper.rb

```
require 'factory_girl'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Then in my spec's I would call it like so

```
person = build(:person)
```

Hope that helps someone. Was looking for about 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this is a correct solution:

```
  @user = Factory(:user)
```

Replace to

```
  @user = Factory.create(:user)
```